# Could not resolve property from Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, single-page-application

I have these entities configuration:

Main table:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Merchants {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "merchants")
    private List<Contracts> contracts;
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Contracts {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "merchant_id")
    private Merchants merchants;
}
```

I use this JPA query:

```
String hql = "select e from " + Contracts.class.getName() + " e where e.merchant_id = ?";

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, merchantId);
```

Table column merchant_id is present when I deploy the package.
But I get exception during SQL query:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: merchant_id of: org.rest.api.entity.Contracts [select e from org.rest.api.entity.Contracts e where e.merchant_id = ?]
```

Do you have any idea why merchant_id is no mapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There need to use Merchants id.

Try with this:

```
String hql = "select e from " + Contracts.class.getName() + " e where e.merchants.id = ?";
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. Is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: i don't know other solution for hql query. You can use JpaSpecification if dont want to use hql